# Web mode HTML tag highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, web-mode

First off, a picture of what I see, editing a handlebars file:

[image: tag highlighting]

My colour theme is base16-grayscale, so that blue is probably hard coded somewhere.

I asked on the web-mode mailing list, but was told to ask here instead.

Can I disable and/or change the colour of this highlighting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To disable the behavior..

Programmatically:

```
(setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight nil)
```

> web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight is a variable defined in
>   ‘web-mode.el’. Its value is nil
>
> Documentation: Disable element highlight.

Interactively:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `web-mode-toggle-current-element-highlight` <kbd>return</kbd>

> web-mode-toggle-current-element-highlight is an interactive compiled
>   Lisp function in ‘web-mode.el’.
>
> (web-mode-toggle-current-element-highlight)
>
> Toggle highlighting of the current html element.

To continue to use the highlighting and just use a better color:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "web-mode"
  '(set-face-background 'web-mode-current-element-highlight-face "your-color"))
```

You can find what face is applied to text a number of ways. If you can get your cursor on the text. You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-face` which will give you a default option of the current face. Or you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-char` which will tell you what face is applied. You can customize faces through the `customize` feature or with elisp. If you can't get your cursor on the face, try finding the face using `customize-group`, `list-faces-display` or by reading the packages code.

Comment: The user might also be interested in how to figure out which face to modify: (1) Navigate to the text with face you want to modify (2) `M-x describe-char` (helpful if the point has multiple faces) (3) Navigate to "There are text properties here:" section (4) Click on the face you want to modify (5) Click on "Customize this face" link in the buffer that pops up (6) Modify as needed and save (7) the customized face will be auto saved in your init.el or your `custom-file`.